# g++ compiler on visual studio 2013

Tags: c++, g++, builder, visual-studio-2013

I'm kind of new to code and use builders for C++ in Windows because I always coded in Linux using the g++ compiler. I just want to know if it is possible to get a similar compiler/builder to "install" or use it in visual studio. It would be awesome if I could maybe use the g++ compiler on windows (preferably in visual studio) if it is possible?

And if it is possible, how do I go about the download and installations of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/)!! Great opensource G++ compiler. Follow the instructions on site. 
If you want something more dedicated, use [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/). Visual studio also has its own version of `g++` with `cl`.

Comment: what does "Visual studio also has its own version of g++ with cl" mean? Are you referring to the C/C++ compiler that comes with VS? If so then it is not a version of G++.

Answer (score 1):

You could check this project:

[CLangVSx](http://www.ishani.org/web/articles/code/clangvsx/) ([GitHub repository](https://github.com/ishani/ClangVSx))

It's an add-in that allows easy use of Clang compiler from inside Visual Studio, replacing the MSVC compiler when building C++ projects.

CLang++ is not G++ but probably it's linux-flavoured enough to make you feel at home.

Answer (score 0):

> (preferably in visual studio) if it is possible?

Don't think so, not with [Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio) (never tried though). Use [Eclipse CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/), it will support VS (microsoft's compiler toolchain) the other way round.

Most open toolchain to use for native windows builds is [MinGw](http://www.mingw.org/) IMHO.

Comment: it is not clear why Joe_B needed G++. Visual Studio has a C/C++ compiler so when using VS it is not likely we need G++. Since Joe_B asked about using G++ with Visual Studio I think it is relevant to say it is not possible or at least not reasonable to do that. When questions are not clear there is often controversy about what is a good answer.

Comment: @user34660 The question isn't very clear, and probably my answer isn't clear enough as well. As I understood it OP asked if he can use a different toolchain (like GCC) in favor of the builtin one. With Visual Studio 2013 that wasn't possible IIRC.